# How to sort Youtube subscriptions by updates?

Tags: youtube, sorting

When I enter YT on the left pane I have "Subscriptions" section sorted by the date of the subscription. So as the effect I could have:

```
Subscriptions
  A 
  D 1
  E
  F
  G 7
  --- show more ---
  B 3
  K 2
```

The letter stands for the channel name, and the number for new videos posted for that channel. The problem is YT puts updated channels as hidden part (of "show more") as well.

I would like to change it so the primary sorting would move updated channels at top, secondary sorting criteria for me is irrelevant, so I could have:

```
Subscriptions
  B 3
  K 2
  D 1
  G 7
  A 
  --- show more ---
  E
  F
```

Is there a way to do this? If yes, how?